# Find a particular solution to the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to solve the following multiple choice question, but I'm not getting the right answer.

> To find a particular solution of the inhomogenous differential equation $$(D-1)^2 (D-2)(D^2+1)y = e^x + \cos x - 2 \sin x$$ one can use the following solution.

And then it gives five choices for which the correct answer is apparently $A_0x^2 e^x + x(A_1 \cos x + A_2 \sin x)$.

But I don't seem to get that when I use the method of annihilators (what I think we're supposed to be using).  I have that $D-1$ annihilates $e^x$, and $D^2+1$ annihilates $\cos x$ and $-2 \sin x$.  Therefore I multiply both sides of the original equation to get $$(D-1)^3 (D-2)(D^2+1)^2y = 0$$ for which the general solution is $$Ae^x + Bxe^x + Cx^2 e^x + De^{2x} + \cos x(E+Fx) + \sin x(G + Hx)$$ If you remove the terms which show up on the right hand side of the original equation, you're just left with $$Bxe^x + Cx^2 e^x + De^{2x} + Fx \cos x + Gx \sin x$$ I don't think I understand the method of annihilators very well (I just learned this like an hour ago).  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This can be done with method of undetermined coefficients

Comment: Sorry, but could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Ok i will try to post an answer, it's bit long for comments, until then you can check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients

Comment: In the method of annihilators you don't remove the right hand terms of the ODE from your solution, you remove the terms in the homogeneous solution to the ODE.  The homogeneous solution to this ODE is $(Ax+b)e^x + Ce^{2x} + D\sin(x)+E\cos(x)$.  So from the long potential particular solution you found, you need to remove the $e^x, xe^x, e^{2x}$ and $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ terms.  This leaves the $x^2e^x$, $x\cos(x)$ and $x\sin(x)$ terms, and hence the given answer.

Comment: Oh thanks, that's what I was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complimentary function of your problem is $$y_c=(c_1+xc_2)e^x+c_3e^{2x}+c_4\sin{x}+c_5\cos{x}.......(1)$$ 
Right side of the equation reads as $$e^x+\cos{x}-2\sin{x}$$

Now by method of variation of parameters, UC sets are $$S_1=\{e^x\}$$
$$S_2=\{\sin{x},\cos{x}\}$$
$$S_3=\{\cos{x},\sin{x}\}$$
Since $S_2$ and $S_3$ are same, we take only one of them. Since $e^x$ and $xe^x$ appears in $(1)$ so $S_1$ is multiplied by $x^2$ and similarly multipling $S_2$ by $x$ we get 
$$S_1=\{x^2e^x\}$$
$$S_2=\{x\sin{x},x\cos{x}\}$$
Now we take the particular integral to be $$y_p=Ax^2e^x+Bx\sin{x}+Cx\cos{x}$$

**Note** This answer is provided using method of undetermined coefficients (UC), so you can see any ODE book to know about the method.